# Export table to CSV file missing column info

Tags: php, wordpress, export-to-csv

I have this script to export a custom admin table to a CSV file. It works perfectly **except for** the "Ref" column which is empty.

The mysql query outputs the right values for the "Ref" column (0001, 0002, 0003...) but in the CSV file the column is empty? Do you know the reason why?

```
    add_action('wp_ajax_csv_pull','csv_pull_wpse_212972');

    function csv_pull_wpse_212972() {
        $arrayStatus = array(0 => 'Libero', 1 => 'Prenotato', 2 => 'Pagato');
        global $wpdb;

            $table_name = $wpdb->prefix . 'wlist_transactions';
            $tblCustomers = $wpdb->prefix . 'wlist_customers';
            $tblSpouses = $wpdb->prefix . 'wlist_spouses';

            $sql = "SELECT $table_name.ID,
                             $table_name.Ref AS Referenza,
                             $table_name.PaymentMethod AS MetodoPagamento,
                             $table_name.PaymentDate AS DataPagamento,
                             $table_name.Amount AS Totale,
                             $table_name.Status,
                             $tblCustomers.Customer as Cliente,
                             $tblSpouses.Names as Spousi,
                             $tblSpouses.Data
                             FROM $table_name
                             left join $tblCustomers on $table_name.Customer = $tblCustomers.ID
                             left join $tblSpouses on $tblCustomers.ID_Spouses = $tblSpouses.ID";

        $file = 'lista_transazioni'; 

        $results = $wpdb->get_results($sql, ARRAY_A);

        if (empty($results)) {
            return;
        }

        $csv_output = '"'.implode('";"',array_keys($results[0])).'";'."\n";;

        foreach ($results as $row) {
        $row['Status'] = $arrayStatus[$row['Status']];
            $csv_output .= '"'.implode('";"', $row).'";'."\n";
        }
        $csv_output .= "\n";

        $filename = $file."_".date("Y-m-d_H-i",time());
        header("Content-type: application/vnd.ms-excel");
        header("Content-disposition: csv" . date("Y-m-d") . ".csv");
        header( "Content-disposition: filename=".$filename.".csv");
        print $csv_output;
        exit;
    }
```

Comment: What do you get when you `var_dump($row);` just inside your `foreach`?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that this column holds numbers with leading zeros. To display them properly in excel you need to prefix them with an '

So try

```
    foreach ($results as $row) {
        $row[1] = '\''.(string)$row[1];
        $row['Status'] = $arrayStatus[$row['Status']];
        $csv_output .= '"'.implode('";"', $row).'";'."\n";
    }
```

Maybe you don't need to cast them to string.

Comment: I also tried this $row['Referenza'] = '\''.(string)$row['Referenza']; but didn't work :(

Comment: what is the output of "var_dump($row)" in one of the data-rows?

Comment: array(9) {
  ["ID"]=>
  string(2) "10"
  ["Referenza"]=>
  string(5) "0003
"
  [MetodoPagamento""]=>"
  string(8) "Contanti"
  ["DataPagamento"]=>
  string(10) "2018-06-25"
  ["Totale"]=>
  string(4) "2000"
  ["Status"]=>
  string(9) "Prenotato"
  ["Cliente"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["Spousi"]=>
  string(17) "Romeo e Giulietta"
  ["Data"]=>
  string(10) "2018-09-09"
}

Comment: Cant think of an error here. Did you open the csv with excel? Open it with an normal text editor an check whats in column 2.